# html: My website does not show the correct frame when navigating links

Tags: html, url, dns, frame

I have links and tabs on my home page of my portfolio, and links to others sites in my tabs, but the correct frame of the url does not change to the new url.

example page
http://www.mydomain.com/ is the home page, but when I navigate to new links the URL bar shows the home frame still, even though the links take the user to a new site.

How can I fix this in html, php, or javascript

Comment: This ought to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find any...

Comment: Please show your work; post and format some samples of what you have already tried, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

To cause a link to load in the top level frame set the target of the link to "_top"

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/otherpage.html" target="_top">My Link</a>
```

See the [W3Schools Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)